# Argument that a maximum density Universe expands linearly

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion

The Friedmann equation for a spatially flat Universe is given by
$$\Big(\frac{\dot R}{R}\Big)^2=\frac{8 \pi G}{3}\rho$$
where $R(t)$ is the proper radius of some spherical volume with us at its center.

Let us assume that there is a mass $M$ inside this spherical volume of radius $R$. The density $\rho$ is then given by
$$\rho=\frac{M}{(4/3)\pi R^3}.$$
Substituting the above expression for the density $\rho$ into the Friedmann equation gives
$$\Big(\frac{\dot R}{R}\Big)^2=\frac{2 G M}{R^3}.$$
Now let us consider a Universe with a maximum density $\rho$. The maximum density in a spherical volume of radius $R$ is realized by a Black hole whose Schwarzschild radius is equal to $R$. Therefore we have the relationship
$$\frac{GM}{R}=\frac{c^2}{2}.$$ If we substitute the above relationship into the Friedmann equation we obtain
$$\Big(\frac{\dot R}{R}\Big)^2=\frac{c^2}{R^2}$$
which has the linear solution
$$R=c\ t.$$
Therefore it seems that a Universe with a maximum density $\rho$ expands linearly rather than exponentially as would be expected for a de Sitter Universe with a constant Planck scale density.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: But, isn't the equation for a flat universe only valid for $\rho_{crit}$?

Comment: True - I'm assuming that observations have shown that the Universe is approximately spatially flat and therefore $\rho \sim \rho_{crit}$. I also assumed a flat Universe for simplicity so that I can define density using the mass inside a spherical ball. I don't think this assumption affects my argument.